# What is the best way to handle CSV with diff pattern sequence?

Tags: c#, parsing, csv

I am writing a program that parses .txt file with comma delimeter per row. Code is in C#. File is a `.txt`, db is mssql.

The usual sequence is

```
date_aired, 
time_aired_start, 
time_aired_end, 
duration_aired, 
movie_name but
```

found out some of the rows displays in this sequence

```
date_aired, 
time_aired_start, 
duration_aired, 
movie_name.
```

That was no problem as I can just get the time_aired_end by adding time_aired_start with the duration but found out again there is another sequence like this

```
date_aired, 
time_aired_start, 
date_aired, 
time_aired_end, 
movie_name
```

I mean some rows are wiritng in the first pattern while some rows are in 2nd pattern or third in just 1 txt file. There is no way I can determine which code I have to use in parsing each column and put it in my object by index like the code below:

```
AirData aData= new AirData();
aData.dateAir = txtParse[0]
aData.timeStart = txtParse[1]
aData.timeEnd = txtParse[2]
aData.duration = txtParse[3] ...etc.
```

So my question is, what is the best way to handle such situation? The textfiles are handed to me already generated by some machine and I can not correct it. My job is to parse it and store it in the DB so I can generate a report for it.

My thinking is to put it inside try catch and every time it throws an exception, It will try executing the 2nd pattern or the 3rd if another exception is thrown. Is that good? or any suggestion?

**update:**

some actual data. 
the columns here are diff from my sample above coz I just shortcut it.

PATTERN 1: 11 fields

```
01/01/2013,
00:00:00;00,
00:00:54;19,
00:00:54:20,
01/01/2013,
00:00:00;00,
00:00:54;19,
00:00:54:20,
Seg 4 HAPPY NEW YEAR WISHES.mp4,
Aired,
5D189F06-886D-40B1-AC70-609C2CA5E774
```

PATTERN 2: 9 fields - this can be easily spotted as I can just check if array length is more  less than 11

```
01/28/2013,
21:38:23;11,
00:01:00:04,
01/28/2013,21:38:23;11,
00:01:00:04,
ADXEFRF2-0243.mov,
Aired,
9E74C08C-8E30-48A1-A743-44ACC93E183E
```

but here's the problem I have:

PATTERN 3 -ALSO HAVE 11 FIELDS but different sequence.

```
01/28/2013,
21:39:23;15,
00:08:03:01,
01/28/2013,
21:39:23;15,
01/28/2013,
21:47:26;13,
00:08:03:01,
THE IMPOSTOR With Eng Subs Ep 11-5.mp4,
Aired,
895F4F16-5624-4A2C-A5E0-D3BF1BA57B86
```

Comment: Does the text file have headers that you could dynamically use to determine the sequence of columns?

Comment: Using exceptions as flow control is considered bad practice, so you should find another way.

Comment: Could you use some sort of pattern matching to decide between the 3 formats? Could you show some of the actual data, in those formats?

Comment: nope the txt files do not have headers.

Answer (score 0):

You could use some Regular expressions & test each field as you parse the file.

Case 2 is easily spotted as it only has 4 columns, not 5. Case 1 & 3 are hard to tell apart without knowing what format `time_aired_end` & `duration_aired` is in (eg is 01:30 is 1 hour 30 minutes, 1 minute 30 sec, 30 minutes past 1 am, or 30 minutes past 1 pm)